# Multiplying by 2 every other element in a list starting from the end of the list

Tags: python-3.x, list, integer, list-comprehension

I want to make a list that multiplies its elements by 2 starting from the end with a step of -2. For example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
# I want it to return a = [2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6, 14]
```

I had some ideas but nothing I try works. Take a look at my code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a = [i*2 for i in a[-1::-2]]
print(a)

#or
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in a[-1::-2]:
    i *= 2
#returns only 14, 10, 6, 2
```

Comment: Use `enumerate` to only multiply the correct indexes. Use `len` to determine if the list has odd or even number of elements: `[n*2 if i%2!=len(a)%2 else n for i,n in enumerate(a)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had almost the correct logic. Loop on the **indices** an assign back to the list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 

for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -2):
    a[i] *= 2
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6, 14]
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the response. I would like to ask another question. If this time i had the list `list = [8, 9, 1]` and I wanted to return `list = [8, 18, 1]` what should I change in this code?

Comment: It depends on the logic, you can maybe start from the second to last item? `range(len(a)-2, -1, -2)`?